# No message template exists for key 'emailAddressInvalidFormat' zf2

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2, zend-inputfilter

No message template exists for key *emailAddressInvalidFormat*-zf2 [zend-framework2].

I am using following code, My array for filter is

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'email',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'StringLength',
                'options' => array(
                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                    'min' => 1,
                    'max' => 256,
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'DoctrineModule\Validator\ObjectExists',
                'options' => array(
                    'object_repository' =>  $sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')->getRepository('Application\Entity\Customer'),
                    'fields' => 'email',
                     'messages'=>array(
                        \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT  => "Invalid type given. String expected",
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ));
```

But i am getting error.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing doesn't make much sense.
Try once to not set custom messages. Just omit the messages key totally.

```
array(
    'name' => 'DoctrineModule\Validator\ObjectExists',
    'options' => array(
        'object_repository' =>  $sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')->getRepository('Application\Entity\Customer'),
        'fields' => 'email',
    )
),
```

It should work correctly if you do that. Currently you are configuring the `ObjectExists` validator with the keys of the `EmailAddress` validator, so you are mixing things up.

If you feel the need to customize things the message key should be `noObjectFound` or `\DoctrineModule\Validator\ObjectExists::ERROR_NO_OBJECT_FOUND;`